# Selenium Crashes in Try Block

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

So I'm using the JavaScript implementation of Selenium, WebDriverJS. I'm rather new to WebDriverJS, and I'm wondering, why does the code crash within a Try block? It never even gets to the Catch block. Here is my code:

```
    try
    {
        driver.findElement(this.By.xpath("html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/center[1]/div[15]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]")).click();
    catch (err)
    {
        driver.findElement(this.By.xpath("html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/center[1]/div[15]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]")).click();
    }
```

Then I get this error message in the console:

NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/center[1]/div[15]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]"}

As you can see, this error comes from the code within the Try block.

Is there any way I can make the code continue executing despite this error?

Comment: It is likely that your catch statement is throwing an error too.

Comment: No, I've already test the code in the catch block, it's working correctly.

Comment: xpath is very finicky too. It's better to use css paths, like this.By.css("div.someClass > a > img:nth-child(2)"). You can test CSS paths in your browser console by using document.querySelector("div.someClass")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebdriverJS fires off "findElements" asynchronously ([docs here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebElementPromise.html)), which means that your statement will clear that try catch, then the callback throws an error. To catch the error properly, use the [promise pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
// Original implementation    
driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'}).click();

// Promise usage, my preference
driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'}).then(function(el) {
  return el.click();
}).catch(function(err){
  //handle error here
})

// Another way to resolve the error
driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'}).then(el, function (err) {
  if (err && err.name === "NoSuchElementError"){
    return console.log("Element was missing!");
  }

  return el.click();  
});
```